# OrientDB1.0.1 - Unable to process 34 million records

Tags: orientdb

We are using OrientDB 1.0.1 and I need to process a class/table of 34 million records. On my machine with 8 GB memory, I am getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" error after inserting about 1 million records. 96% of my physical memory is occupied. Increasing JVM heap size to 8 GB, helped in processing 2 million records but it failed at 2 millions. I tried on a physical machine with 16 GB and this problem occurred after processing 3.8 million records. I need to process all 34 million records and find unique ids. The problem seems to be clearly with orientdb's buffers getting filled.

```
int skipRecordCount=0;
String queryStr = "select id from Table1 WHERE id is not null SKIP +Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000";
Set uniqueIdsSet = new TreeSet(); 
List idsResult = odb.db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery(queryStr)); 
while (!idsResult.isEmpty()) 
{ 
    for (ODocument id: idsResult) 
    { 
        uniqueIdsSet.add(id.field("id").toString()); 
    } 
    skipRecordCount+=10000; 
    queryStr = "select id from Table1 WHERE id is not null SKIP "+Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000"; 
    idsResult = odb.db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery(idsQueryStr)); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why you use such old database version? Could you use 2.2.x instead?

Comment: The latest version of OrientDB is 2.2.20. the version you are using is at least 5 years old.

Comment: OrientDB 1.0.1? It's like you want to watch a movie in UHD on a C64...

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. We are planning to upgrade to the latest version in the next release. But some of the customers are already using our product with older version and we need to delete duplicate records of certain data. Hence I need to read them.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a testcase for 2.2.20

I've added an index hash notunique, without null, and successfully executed all the test with 2 million records, random ids, in 3 minutes, using in memory testdb, on a 16gb system (osx), with 12gb heap max (not needed!), and process size was 4.9gb

When I changed to 34 millions the insert phase of testcase, for random ids, was completed in 33 minutes, with a process size of 7.2gb (3gb direct), then created index in 15 minutes, with a process size of 8.2gb (4gb direct), and completed quickly the testcase with add of unique ids in TreeSet

Used

```
"CREATE INDEX test.id NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX METADATA {ignoreNullValues : true}"
```

and

```
"SELECT key FROM index:test.id WHERE key NOT IN [NULL] SKIP "+Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000"
```

```
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OClass;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OSchema;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.metadata.schema.OType;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQL;
import com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.query.OSQLSynchQuery;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class SelectUniqueIDs {

public static void createTreeSet (ODatabaseDocumentTx db) {

    int skipRecordCount=0;
    String queryStr = "select id from test WHERE id is not null SKIP "+Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000";
    Set uniqueIdsSet = new TreeSet(); 
    List<ODocument> idsResult = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery(queryStr)); 
    while (!idsResult.isEmpty()) 
    { 
        for (ODocument id: idsResult) 
        { 
            uniqueIdsSet.add(id.field("id").toString()); 
        } 
        skipRecordCount+=10000; 

        // queryStr = "SELECT id FROM test WHERE id IS NOT NULL SKIP "+Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000"; 
        // Using above query index on test.id is not used as we see from message, starting from skip 50000 
        // INFO: $ANSI{green {db=test}} [TIP] Query 'SELECT id FROM test WHERE id IS NOT NULL SKIP 50000 LIMIT 10000' fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent index

        queryStr = "SELECT key FROM index:test.id WHERE key NOT IN [NULL] SKIP "+Integer.toString(skipRecordCount)+" LIMIT 10000"; 
        idsResult = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery(queryStr)); 
    }
    System.out.println("**** Inserted "+uniqueIdsSet.size()+" ids in uniqueIdsSet TreeSet ****");
}
  public static final void main(String[] args) {

    int i;

    long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("**** Initial Heap maxMemory="+maxMemory+" , totalMemory="+totalMemory+" , freeMemory="+freeMemory+" ****");

    final ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("memory:testdb").create();
    final OSchema schema = db.getMetadata().getSchema();
    final OClass clazz = schema.createClass("test");
    clazz.createProperty("id", OType.DOUBLE);

    for (i=0 ;  i < 34000000; i++){
        int r =(int)(Math.random() * 100000 + 1);
        db.command(new OCommandSQL("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES ("+r+")")).execute();
    }

    db.command(new OCommandSQL("CREATE INDEX test.id NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX METADATA {ignoreNullValues : true}")).execute();

    maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long insertMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("**** Inserted "+i+" ids; Heap maxMemory="+maxMemory+" , totalMemory="+totalMemory+" , freeMemory="+insertMemory+" ****");

    createTreeSet(db);

    final List<ODocument> count = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery("SELECT count(*) as ids FROM test"));
    Long ids = (Long) count.get(0).field("ids");

    maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long countMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("**** Counted "+ids+" ids; Heap maxMemory="+maxMemory+" , totalMemory="+totalMemory+" , freeMemory="+countMemory+" ****");

    final List<ODocument> docs = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery("SELECT FROM test LIMIT 100"));

    for (i=0 ;  i < 10; i++){
        Double value = (Double) docs.get(i).field("id");
        System.out.print(i+"="+value+" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
    totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
    long selectMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    System.out.println("**** Selected "+i+" ids;  Heap maxMemory="+maxMemory+" , totalMemory="+totalMemory+" , freeMemory="+selectMemory+" ****");


  }
}
```